# Why does "WHERE text != "something" also exclude all rows with NULL values?

Tags: mysql, sql

*Sorry, this is probably a really frequent question, but I really don't know how to phrase a google search that finds it.*

**SELECT * FROM table where textfield != "Word";**

1. This ignores all rows where the textfield has the string "Word" - but it also ignores all rows where textfield is NULL. Why?
2. What is the correct way of selecting ALL rows (even NULLS), except rows with a specific string in a text field?

Comment: Because `NULL` means UNKNOWN. Therefor you cannot say it is equal or unequal to something KNOWN. Hence, a comparison with `NULL` will always return `NULL`, which is not TRUE.

Comment: That's how null comparison works! Do `where (textcolumn <> "Word" or textcolumn is null)`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Almost all comparisons with `NULL` return `NULL` (the most common excepts are `IS NULL` and `IS NOT NULL`).  And in `WHERE` clauses, `NULL` is treated the same as "false" -- that is, the rows are filtered.

MySQL offers a `NULL`-safe comparison operator.  You can use:

```
where not textfield <=> 'Word'
```

`<=>` returns `true` or `false` -- never `NULL` -- so it does what you expect.

Let me add:  The SQL Standard has a `NULL`-safe operator.  So, in Standard SQL, this would be:

```
where textfield is distinct from 'Word'
```

However, not many databases support the standard syntax -- yet.

Comment: upvlote for discussing `<=>`

Answer (score 2):

You need to tell the database to include the rows where `textfield` is NULL:

```
SELECT *
  FROM table
  WHERE textfield != 'Word' OR
        textfield IS NULL
```

In a relational database any direct comparison to NULL (using comparison operators such as `=`, `<>` or `!=`, `<`, `>`, `<=`, or `>=`) will return NULL or UNKNOWN (depending on the database). This is intentional and by design - but it *does* make it a bit awkward sometimes. If you want NULLs included you need to specify that.

In some databases you can use the `NVL` or `COALESCE` functions to provide a "default value" to replace NULLs with, as in:

```
SELECT *
  FROM table
  WHERE NVL(textfield, 'X') != 'Word'
```

or

```
SELECT *
  FROM table
  WHERE COALESCE(textfield, 'X') != 'Word'
```

`COALESCE` is the ANSI version, allows multiple arguments, and is the preferred solution. For example, if you want to return `textfield`, but if was NULL you wanted to return `text2`, and then if `text2` was *also* NULL you wanted to return `X` you could use

```
SELECT *
  FROM table
  WHERE COALESCE(textfield, text2, 'X') != 'Word'
```